# How to stream statuses of only LIST timeline using tweepy python module?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I can retrieve status of list_timeline on each execution or loop it and compare it with previous status and print only new status but I want to stream it so whenever new status arrives in list timeline my code block get trigger.

```
list_status=api.list_timeline(list_id=list_id, count=1)
print(list_status.text)
```

I have tried streaming user home timeline, keywords and hashtags but could not find way to stream 'list timeline'

Comment: There is no streaming API for a lists timeline. You have to poll for new entries.

Comment: Thank you. is there free way to avoid polling and only get triggered when data changes. So that I can pass the url of list and get json?

Comment: There is no way to do that, paid or free - the lists APIs are polling-only.